# With an iPhone game, can I allow music from other apps to play while my game is being played?

Tags: iphone, music, sound-effects

My game doesn't have any music but it does have sound effects. Right now if I power up Pandora and then start a song and then switch to my game it will stop the Pandora song. Is there a special way I need to play my sound fx so that the music from Pandora will keep playing while my game is running?

Answer (score 3):

If you set up your Audio Session type to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` you'll get mixing with whatever's playing in the background:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient